# How to add custom checkbox fee in checkout page?

Tags: magento2

How to add custom checkbox fee in checkout page while click that checkbox that fee will add into the order total or uncheck that it will reverse from order total?

Comment: live:tusharlathiya1996 i can guide you, To adding the custom fee related things,

Comment: yes sure please

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:**

To add the custom checkbox on the checkout page. You need to add below code to the checkout_index_index.xml file.

```
<item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="productcheck" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]_[Modulename]/js/view/checkout-checkbox</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Place the provided code in the designated section on the checkout page layout xml to display the checkbox.

Apart from the above, You will require to create the knockout JS file, where you will define the default template for the checkbox.

**Here is the JS code:**

```
define(["ko", "uiComponent", "Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals"], function (
    ko,
    Component,
    totals
) {
    "use strict";

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: "[Namespace]_[Modulename]/checkout-form",
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the HTML template:**

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optinout" data-bind="checked:true, attr: {id: 'opt-in'}" />
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'opt-in'}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Opt for Pricing'"></span></label>
</div>
```

Rest you have to create the JS functions to update the cart total on checkbox check/uncheck.

Hope this will help you to implement the same.